# How do I remove a require_once admin panel from the parent theme from the child theme functions.php?

Tags: php, functions, admin, child-theme

In the parent theme, the following is at the bottom of the **functions.php** file.

```
require_once(TEMPLATEPATH . '/admin/admin-menu.php');
```

In the child theme's **function.php**, this code will include the child admin panel.

```
require_once(STYLESHEETPATH . '/admin/admin-menu.php');
```

As you can see, I shouldn't use both files b/c the bottom file includes `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead of `get_template_directory_uri()` for certain localized files (js, css). Thus, I need to remove the parent file from loading

I believe I need to use the `remove_action` hook, but I'm not sure how to do this right. Can't find a good answer on Google either.

I started writing the following in the **functions.php** file in my child theme, but I don't know how to write it properly.

```
function remove_parent_admin_panel {
   remove_action('remove_panel', '[WHAT-GOES-HERE?]');
}
```

Then I guess I need to use a `add_action` hook to add the above function to remove the parent admin panel.

Should I wrap the parent `require_once` with a function statement? Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For cases where you want to require/include PHP files, but still allow child themes to replace those PHP files outright, then you should use the locate_template function.

Example: Parent does this:

`locate_template( 'admin/file.php', true );`

This finds the admin/file.php file in either the child or the parent theme, then does a require on it (that's what the true is for).

So to replace the file in the child, you just replace the file in the child. Simple. Easy.

Note: The method defaults to using require_once. If you just want to require only, then pass a third parameter of false.

Comment: Interesting, that's good to know. So, what you're saying is that, in both child and parent **functions.php** files, I should include the code you wrote above?

Comment: No, in the child theme you don't have to include anything but the modified file. The parent will make the locate_template call, and that call will *automatically* load the admin/file.php from the child instead of the parent, if the child has such a file. This is the basis for child theme file replacements, the parent makes the call, and the child can then replace specific files without any special coding at all.

Comment: Wow, that's awesome. In all the reading I did about child themes, I never saw this but it's very useful and seems to work correctly for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Otto is there a function I can use within my child themes functions file so that I don't modify my parent themes functions file? My parent theme also has `require_once( get_template_directory() . '/function-includes/theme-functions.php' );` and replacing it with `locate_template` works but if my client updates their theme it will overwrite  this small mod. Is there any alternative?

Comment: If the parent is written incorrectly, no amount of fiddling with the child will necessarily be able to fix it. Fix the parent, get the parent theme to have the fix in it.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the Parent Theme's `\admin\admin-menu.php` file, look for the function `add_menu_page()`. It should be wrapped in a function, and that function called in an `add_action( 'admin_init', 'function-name' )` call.

You need to call `remove_action( 'admin_init', 'function-name' )` for whatever that function name is.